# Is it possible to simulate a 'belt' between two joints?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I would like to constrain two joints together with a "belt" so that the angles of the two joints remain the same while allowing the forces on each joint to effect the other. Is this possible?

Think of a skid-steer robot with a single motor driving both wheels on the same side of the robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1757/is-it-possible-to-simulate-a-%27belt%27-between-two-joints?/) by [dereck](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/219/dereck/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 86 on 2013-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

there is a [pull request](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/300/added-ode-gearbox-constraint-with-error/diff) (it's just fallen a bit out of date) but [the ode_gearbox branch](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/5d1cb7767586?at=ode_gearbox) should still work.  An [example world](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/5d1cb7767586834bc7df07a003a0be9c4c03db7b/sdf/worlds/gearbox.world?at=ode_gearbox) and an [unit test](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/5d1cb7767586/test/regression/physics.cc?at=ode_gearbox#cl-227) can be found.  With this, you can simulate gears with arbitrary ratios, the transmission is enforced by constraints.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1